# Important to learn is this stuff

Tags: infinitives, complements, predicative-complements

**This song is fun to sing.**

**This pizza is too hot to eat.**

Is the infinitive there considered a complement of the predicate adjective?

Comment: I think it is an ***adverb infinitive***: An infinitive is to *plus* a verb form. It can be used as an adverb. 
*Adverb infinitives* are used to modify verbs. They usually tell why. Adverb infinitives are used to modify predicate adjectives. They may also be compound. http://www.dailygrammar.com/Lesson-235-Adverb-Infinitives.htm

Answer (score 3):

> 1. This song is fun to sing.
> 2. This pizza is too hot to eat.

**Sentence 1**

In the first sentence the infinitival clause *to sing* is a hollow infinitival clause functioning as the Complement of the adjective *fun*. Notice that the song itself could be depressing but it could be fun to sing. The fact that *to sing* is a hollow clause here is specifically because of the adjective *fun*. The adjective *fun* dictates that our interpretation of the Object of the infinitival clause is determined by the Subject of the matrix clause. We understand the sentence like this:

- **This song** is fun to sing [<s>**it**</s>]

The Subject of the infinitival clause is just determined from the  context. We could reconstruct the sentence like this:

- This song is fun [for people to sing [<s>**it**</s>]]

In some grammars these types of adjectives are called *TOUGH ADJECTIVES*.

**Sentence 2**

Sentence (2) looks very similar to sentence (1). However, it's very different. Consider the following sentences:

- <sup>?</sup>This pizza is hot to give to a child
- <sup>?</sup>This course is long to finish.

Neither of these sentences is very good. The reason is that neither *hot* nor *long* tend to take hollow infinitival clauses as Complements. They are not very good at being *tough*-adjectives.

However, if we modify these adjectives with the degree adverb *too*, they become perfectly grammatical and felicitous:

- This pizza is too hot to give to a child.
- This course is too long to finish.

The reason that these sentences are ok is that the hollow infinitival clause is licensed by the deictic degree adverb *too*. Similarly, the infinitival clause *hot to eat* in the Original Poster's sentence number (2) is similarly licensed by the adverb *too*. Notice, however, that the adverb *too* cannot license the infinitival clause unless it has a following adjective to modify:

- *The pizza is too to eat. (ungrammatical)

Also notice that unlike other words that take Complements, the word *too* does not form a phrase directly with its Complement. For this reason CaGEL say that the infinitival clause is the Indirect Complement of the adjective *hot*. Notice that this is very different from being a bona fide Complement of an adjective as in sentence (1).

**Conclusion**

The infinitival phrase is a Complement of the adjective *fun* in sentence (1). However, the infinitival clause is not a Complement of the adjective in sentence (2) where it is licensed by the Modifier *too* not by the adjective itself. Some grammars would refer to the infinitival clause here as an Indirect Complement of the adjective *hot*.

---

<sup>**References:**</sup>

<sup>*CaGEL* is an abbreviation for *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Huddleston & Pullum, 2002.</sup>

Comment: The slope is slippery to walk on.